# JavaScript Select element in the way like CSS in proper way

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select a `tbody` tag with no id or class or tags or whatever...

In CSS I know that I can use the following to select it:

```
table#header_info > tbody
```

But how can I achieve the same thing in JavaScript / jQuery?  What is the best way?

Comment: Would you not do the same with jQuery? $("table#header_info > tbody").yourOperations...

Comment: If you use jQuery only for selecting elements, remove that jQuery and use 4. But if you use jQuery on your page and you want to load 24KB script into you page the first one is the fastest. (but you could remove table). The second one is wrong, see my comment at Rick Burns answer.

Comment: Alright, then i will use the first one, because i already use JQuery. Thanks for the reply's guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery:

```
var tbody = $('#header_info').children('tbody');
```

In MooTools:

```
var tbody = $('header_info').getChildren('tbody');
```

In DoJo:

```
var tbody = dojo.query('tbody', '#header_info');
```

In Raw JS:

```
var tbody = document.querySelectorAll("#header_info > tbody ");
```

In Raw JS old version:

```
var tbody = document.getElementById('header_info').getElementsByTagName('tbody');
```

And there are many many other JavaScript Selecting Engines and functions that you can use...

Answer (score 2):

Just like CSS, in jQuery...

```
var tbody = $('#header_info > tbody')
```

I removed the unnecessary `table` selector, but you can keep it if you want.

---

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can do:

```
$("#header_info").children("tbody");
```

Or:

```
$("#header_info > tbody");
```

Comment: #header_info tbody or #header_info > tbody is a big difference. The first one selects all tbody tags that are descendant of #header_info and the second one selects only the tbody tags that are children of #header_info

Comment: @WouterJ Missed the parent/child operator in OP's example, edited my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll("table#header_info > tbody ");
```

But this won't work on some of old browsers. You should use jquery

```
$("table#header_info > tbody")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using plain JavaScript, you can use `getElementsByTagName()`

```
// This retrieves the first `<tbody>` found as a child of the node with
// id `header_info`
document.getElementById('header_info').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select a tbody in a table with an ID of header_info, like your CSS above.

```
$("#header_info tbody")
```